# fixing code that outputs csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I need my code to output all the user in the class's score but it only output one user answer a lot of times. Please can you help. Thanks in advance.

```
filename = class_name + ".csv"

csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')

with open(filename, 'a',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data=[[name,score]]              
    a.writerow(data)


if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = 'pipes')
        for row in reader:
            print (data)
else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing `print(row)`.

`print(data)` just prints the last *output* data list that you wrote.